# TCPDF Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 25368 bytes)

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using the TCPDF library to simultaneously download pdf's onto my local drive.

PHP CODE:

```
$text = //an array of id's
$id = explode(',', $text);
for ($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){
    if(//id[$i] exists in database){
           createPDF($id[$i],'test123','F');
    }
}
```

`createPDF` is where the tcpdf library is used to create pdf's.

This works, and the first few pdf's are generated, but soon enough, I get an error saying:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 25368 bytes)...

Is there a way I could fix this? or is it a `tcpdf` bug?

Answer (score 2):

In this case please increase the memory limit for the script through the `ini_set()` function.